# License issues of Google Elevation API usage

Tags: google, license

I would like to use Google Elevation API in a non-profit scientific research (river floodplain relief study). I have looked through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=ru#section_10_12), but my poor English leaves me no chances to understand if I am allowed to do this.

I just want to:

1. Parse Google DEM using Google Elevation API;
2. Store the received data locally in shp for future processing;

Received **data will not be displayed** anyway: I am going to use it only for the calculation of specific relief parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the terms are bound to only using the service with Google Maps API

The Elevation API has the following limits in place:

```
2,500 requests per 24 hour period.
512 locations per request.
25,000 total locations per 24 hour period
```

but more importantly 
The **Elevation API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map**; using elevation data without displaying a map for which elevation data was requested is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/#Limits

links to **Google Maps Terms of Use**

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12